# Android SDK cannot fetch repository with system images

Tags: android, sdk, repository

i am having an issue with downloading system images in Android SDK. All components of sdk can be downloaded as usually, but not system images, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: problem_screenshot]

I am using Fedora 23 and OpenJDK.

Has anyone else experienced a simillar issue?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work here as well.
You can download it manually from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml

Eg. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sysimg_armv7a-15_r03.zip

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding custom repository with same url and it's working now, [as seen in the following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjMtb.png).